# Would a laser sail change a relativistic rocket?

Tags: rocket-science

All the relativistic rocket equations I've seen include an onboard fuel mass lessening during the journey. If the ship were instead propelled by a Bessel beam laser sail, would that change things? How?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_propulsion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory it is possible for the ship to be propelled by a distant laser pointing at a light sail, thus eliminating the need to carry fuel for propulsion. However, you would have to have a corresponding laser at your destination to slow you to a stop.